# intermittent error "GPU sync failed" error when running tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gpu

I have have successfully installed Tensorflow and Keras through Anaconda on my NVidia equipped machine, and it works perfect when it works! But sometimes it fails and gives GPU Sync error.

More specifically, after activating Anaconda environment, I can compile and run my model on GPU successfully. But then if I want to compile and run a second model from another python program, I always get this GPU Sync error. When this happens, I have to shut down the environment, reactivate the environment again and start from compiling and running the second model, and it goes all well.

In addition to switching from one model to another model, sometimes I get the same error if I keep rerun the same model again and again.

```
OS: Windows 10 home
GPU: 1050ti
Anaconda 1.9.7
Dev Environment: Jupyter Lab 0.35.4
tensorflow-gpu: 1.13.1
keras-gpu: 2.2.4
```

any help would be appreciated!

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InternalError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\envs\G\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1333     try:
-> 1334       return fn(*args)
   1335     except errors.OpError as e:

~\Anaconda3\envs\G\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _run_fn(feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1318       return self._call_tf_sessionrun(
-> 1319           options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
   1320 

~\Anaconda3\envs\G\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _call_tf_sessionrun(self, options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
   1406         self._session, options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list,
-> 1407         run_metadata)
   1408 

InternalError: GPU sync failed
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
InternalError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-308-f1e49fa98487> in <module>
     15                             Dimension,
     16                             weights=[Embedding_Matrix],
---> 17                             trainable=True))
     18                      my_model_cuda.add(Bidirectional(CuDNNGRU(Dimension, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', kernel_regularizer=None, recurrent_regularizer=None, bias_regularizer=None, activity_regularizer=None, recurrent_initializer='orthogonal', bias_initializer='zeros',return_sequences=True)))

     19 my_model_cuda.add(Bidirectional(CuDNNGRU(Dimension, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', kernel_regularizer=None, recurrent_regularizer=None, bias_regularizer=None, activity_regularizer=None, recurrent_initializer='orthogonal', bias_initializer='zeros',return_sequences=False)))

~\Anaconda3\envs\G\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\sequential.py in add(self, layer)
    163                     # and create the node connecting the current layer
    164                     # to the input layer we just created.
--> 165                     layer(x)
    166                     set_inputs = True
    167             else:

~\Anaconda3\envs\G\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py in __call__(self, inputs, **kwargs)
    434                 # Load weights that were specified at layer instantiation.
    435                 if self._initial_weights is not None:
--> 436                     self.set_weights(self._initial_weights)
    437 
    438             # Raise exceptions in case the input is not compatible

~\Anaconda3\envs\G\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py in set_weights(self, weights)
   1049             return
   1050         weight_value_tuples = []
-> 1051         param_values = K.batch_get_value(params)
   1052         for pv, p, w in zip(param_values, params, weights):
   1053             if pv.shape != w.shape:

~\Anaconda3\envs\G\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py in batch_get_value(ops)
   2418     """
   2419     if ops:
-> 2420         return get_session().run(ops)
   2421     else:
   2422         return []

~\Anaconda3\envs\G\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py in get_session()
    197                 # not already marked as initialized.
    198                 is_initialized = session.run(
--> 199                     [tf.is_variable_initialized(v) for v in candidate_vars])
    200                 uninitialized_vars = []
    201                 for flag, v in zip(is_initialized, candidate_vars):

~\Anaconda3\envs\G\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    927     try:
    928       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 929                          run_metadata_ptr)
    930       if run_metadata:
    931         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

~\Anaconda3\envs\G\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1150     if final_fetches or final_targets or (handle and feed_dict_tensor):
   1151       results = self._do_run(handle, final_targets, final_fetches,
-> 1152                              feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
   1153     else:
   1154       results = []

~\Anaconda3\envs\G\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _do_run(self, handle, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1326     if handle is None:
   1327       return self._do_call(_run_fn, feeds, fetches, targets, options,
-> 1328                            run_metadata)
   1329     else:
   1330       return self._do_call(_prun_fn, handle, feeds, fetches)

~\Anaconda3\envs\G\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1346           pass
   1347       message = error_interpolation.interpolate(message, self._graph)
-> 1348       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
   1349 
   1350   def _extend_graph(self):

InternalError: GPU sync failed
```

Comment: oof, you really need to format your code in this question, otherwise it's essentially unreadable. look through stackoverflow documentation to see how you can format code in a question or answer.